# Gmail API - Get Last Message in Thread [Python]

Tags: python, gmail-api

I´m using the Gmail API to retrieve the last message in a thread.
In the following code, I get all unseen Threads. Then, for each thread, I get the last message. But when I want to get that last message text, I get the hole thread text.

```
import httplib2
import os
import json
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import base64
import email

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))).replace('MailAssistant', '') + '/static/MailAssistant/main/assets/client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def GetMessageBody(service, user_id, msg_id):

        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
        messageMainType = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if messageMainType == 'multipart':
                for part in mime_msg.walk():
                        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                                return part.get_payload()
                return ""
        elif messageMainType == 'text':
                return mime_msg.get_payload()


def get_unread_threads(service, user_id='me'):
    # I get unseen threads
    threads = service.users().threads().list(userId=user_id, q='is:unread').execute().get('threads', [])
    print("Unread Threads: ", len(threads))
    biggest_internal_date = 0
    last_msg = []
    # Iterate each Thread
    for thread in threads:
        # I get those threads info
        tdata = service.users().threads().get(userId=user_id, id=thread['id']).execute()
        # I get the last message from the actual Thread
        for message in tdata['messages']:
            if int(message['internalDate']) > int(biggest_internal_date):
                biggest_internal_date = message['internalDate']
                last_msg = message
        # I get the data from that last message
        print(GetMessageBody(service, user_id, last_msg['id']))


def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    get_unread_threads(service)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I get all the thread messages:

```
tuturuturururlastmessage

On Sat, Feb 17, 2018 at 11:43 PM, Danny Julian <dannyjulian.x@gmail.com>
wrote:

> asdadsadsas
>
> On Fri, Feb 16, 2018 at 12:35 PM, Danny Julian <dannyjulian.x@gmail.com>
> wrote:
>
>> message3
>>
>> On Fri, Feb 16, 2018 at 12:34 PM, Daniel Julian <djulian@x.com>
>> wrote:
>>
>>> message2
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> 2018-02-16 12:33 GMT-03:00 Danny Julian <dannyjulian.x@gmail.com>:
>>>
>>>> message1
>>>>
>>>
>>>
>>
>
```

Is there a way I can only get "tuturuturururlastmessage"? Or I have to find a way to parse the whole thing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Technically you just got a single message, which happens to quote all previous messages back to possibly the first one. This is the last message of the thread, and you returned it correctly.

Incidentally, the GMail web interface (and other mail clients since then) hides the quotes by scraping for cues (typically, indentation or '>' signs).

If you wish to isolate the real contents of the last message from the appended quotes, you'll have to do something similar by parsing and transforming your string.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If it does answer your problem, can I request that you mark the post as answer? Thanks.